# Serializing and Deserializing Custom Exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, deserialization

I'm currently working on exceptions and I've created a custom exception which implements the parent Exception class.

The problem arises when I try to Serialize or Deserialize such a custom exception.

The error is as follows : "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Member 'InnerException' was not found.'"

I've referred to many sources on the internet, but was not able to fix the issue. I'm attaching the code with this body.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public const string DefaultExceptionDescription = "temp";

    public string ExceptionDescription { get; set; }

    public string ReferenceId { get; private set; } = "temp";

    public CustomException(string ExceptionDescription = DefaultExceptionDescription)
    {
        ExceptionDescription = ExceptionDescription;
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    protected CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            ExceptionDescription = info.GetString(nameof(ExceptionDescription));
            ReferenceId = info.GetString(nameof(ReferenceId));
        }
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            info.AddValue(nameof(ExceptionDescription), ExceptionDescription);
            info.AddValue(nameof(ReferenceId), ReferenceId);
        }

        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Fwiw, it's doing that to me on a "stock" `InvalidOperationException` that another API created and serialized, so I'm suspicious it's something underneath your work -- that is, it's not your custom `Exception`, and could be an issue with any `Exception`. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Unless you're maintaining some _very_ old code, you might want to remove that **SecurityPermission** attribute... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/code-access-security/security-and-serialization?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

> The common language runtime throws SerializationException if any type in the graph of objects being serialized does not have the SerializableAttribute attribute applied.

Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-6.0#remarks

Try removing the `SerializableAttribute`

Comment: Hi @Zoidbergseasharp, thanks for your reply, I've tried by removing the Serializable Attribute, initially it throwed an error saying that there is no base constructor, I've created it, but it is not deserializing properly. Can you help me on this issue.